# Changing multiple Windows 10 monitor wallpapers

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, desktop-customization

Today my problem is one of laziness not of necessity, but something that would greatly increase my comfort with Windows 10.

See I have two monitors and I am able to set my wallpaper by opening the "Run" application in Windows, and feeding it:

```
shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper
```

This opens my traditional Desktop Background overview with ease, and lets me set whichever wallpaper I want to whichever screen I want.

The problem is that remembering that line can get rather difficult.

Is there any way I can make a batch file, or generate a shortcut that takes me to said screen? Preferably a shortcut I can just put on my desktop and double-click whenever I want to change wallpapers.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right-click on the Windows 10 desktop and choose New > Shortcut
- When the new shortcut screen displays, enter the Shell command,
  but precede it by the word Explorer as shown in the image. So, the full command will be:

> Explorer shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921}
>   -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper

- Name the shortcut and you are done (but I would go back and change the icon)

[image]